# Do Android Beta testers have access to Productions APK?

Tags: android, google-play, beta

I would like to use the Beta Testing feature of Google Play to test the new version of my app. However, something is confused to me:

Imagine that a user join the Beta Program today, he will get the Beta APK.
Imagine now that in one week I publish a new version of the app (with a higher codeVersion) in the production channel. Do this user will get this update? It seems that if a user want to get the production APK, he has to leave the Beta program AND UNINSTALL the app. Is that true?

To resume, I would like that people in the Beta program also get the Production version if this one is more recent that the Beta. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: _"I would like that people in the Beta program also get the Production version if this one is more recent that the Beta. Is it possible?"_ IIRC, this is the default (and only) behavior. The new production version will have a newer version code than the beta, and hence will be seen as a possible update for everyone, regardless of whether they're in an alpha/beta test program. You'll want to read what Google Play says before you push submit though, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Google Play does not allow the beta version to have a lower version code than the production. If you try to do this the following error pops up:

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>   Version 22 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 22 would receive version 23.

In this example:

- version 22 is the published beta
- version 23 is the new production

This means that before the new production app is uploaded the beta app has to be deactivated.